# Sorting list based on the values of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict `y = {6:34,5:40,3:70,2:80}` and list `m = [5,2,3]` which has only some keys of dict `y`. I have to sort based on values of dict `y = {2:80,3:70,5:40,6:34}` and only consider keys present in list `m` and final result should have sorted `m =[2,3,5]`

Comment: I didnt get ur question ...do you want to sort the list according to its values fron the dict or what ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `sorted()` with a key function which will sort your list based on your dictionary values:

```
>>> sorted(m, key= lambda x: -y.get(x))
[2, 3, 5]
```

Note that since `sorted()` sorts the items in ascending mode you can use negative value of the dict values to make it sort your list descending.  Or you could change the `reverse` argument to `True`:

```
>>> sorted(m, key= lambda x: y.get(x), reverse=True)
[2, 3, 5]
```

Comment: if i have method sort(m,y) i should sort it on the same reference m... so inside method if i do print "Before",m and call sorted(m, key= lambda x: y.get(x), reverse=True) and call print "After",m m should be sorted on the same reference......How do i do it ?

Comment: @SagarR Sorry I can't get you, pleas add your explanation to the question.

Comment: In below code when i call print "After Sorting ", m... it should print [2, 3, 5] Not [5, 2, 3] How do i do it ??                                                               import operator 
def sorting(y,m): 
 sorted(m, key= lambda x: -y.get(x)) 
 
if name == 'main': 
 y = {6:34,5:40,3:70,2:80} 
 m = [5,2,3] 
 print "Before Sorting ", m 
 sorting(y,m) 
 print "After Sorting ", m