# How to sort a list of strings in Python?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I have the following list of lists of strings:

```
a= [['2014'],['2016'],['2017'],['Apr-14'],['Apr-15'],['Apr-16'],['Aug-14'],['Aug-15'],
 ['Aug-16'],['Dec-14'],['Dec-15'],['Dec-16'],['Feb-14'],['Feb-15'],['Feb-16'],['Jan-15'],
 ['Jan-16'],['Jul-14'],['Jul-15'],['Jul-16'],['Jun-14'],['Jun-15'],['Jun-16'],['Mar-14'],
['Mar-15'],['Mar-16'],['May-14'],['May-15'],['May-16'],['Nov-14'],['Nov-15'],['Nov-16'],
['Oct-14'],['Oct-15'],['Oct-16'],['Q115'],['Q116'],['Q214'], ['Q215'],['Q216'],['Q314'],
['Q315'],['Q316'],['Q414'],['Q415'],['Q416'],['Sep-14'],['Sep-15'],['Sep-16'],['Sum 14'],
['Sum 15'],['Sum 16'],['Win 14'],['Win 15'],['Win 16']]
```

I am a python beginner so I don't know how to sort it in the way that I want i know nothing about string manipulation.

I want my output to be:

```
   [['Apr-14'], ['May-14'], ['May-14'], ['Q214'], ['Jun-14'], ['Jul-14'], ['Aug-14'],
['Sep-14'], ['Q314'], ['Sum 14'], ['Oct-14'], ['Nov-14'], ['Dec-14'], ['Q414'],['2014'],
['Jan-15'], ['Feb-15'], ['Mar-15'], ['Q115'], ['Win 14']
    and so on...]
```

How can I do this? It's really hard because for example I have the Win 14 that begins in October 14 but ends in Mar 15 and I have to put 2014 at the end of the year 2014 and so on.

I can't manage to code it I don't even know how I am supposed to write the logic

Comment: I can't tell what is happening here

Comment: what about just the years?

Comment: Are you attempting to sort them by date?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is get your data in a sensible format.  Right now you have months mixed with years mixed with seasons mixed with quarters...  You need to be able to describe *in words* how these elements should be sorted.  (In other words, are you comparing by start date, so `'2014' < 'Mar-14' < 'Win 14'`?  Or by end date, so `'Mar-14' < '2014' < 'Win 14'`?  Or by duration, so `'Mar-14' < 'Win 14' < '2014'`?  etc.)

Comment: Please read [ask], it will help you get better answers.  0x5453's comment will help you focus on what you're doing, but you can give additional information.  Is each element of the outer list really just a single-element list?  Is there a reason it needs to be this way?  Will there ever be more than a single entry in each list?  The title of your question is misleadingly simple.  It's not just sorting a list of strings, it's a list of lists of dates with multiple formats.  Please feel free to [edit] both your title and your question's body.

Comment: The format I want is Janx, Febx, Marchx, Q1x,Win x-1, Aprx, Mayx, Junx, Q2x, Julx, Augx, Sepx, Q3, Sumx Octx, Novx, Decx, Q4x, x, Jan x+1, Febx+1, .... Basically the 3 months then their quarter then the other three month then their quarter then the 'season'that is described by these months, then 3 months then quarter then three months then Quarter then their year

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious to me how the ranges within a year should be ordered, particularly 'sum' and 'win'.  I would recommend sorting in two stages.  First look at the last 2 characters on each string in the list to sort by year.  Then, create a dictionary containing all possible ranges with it's sort order as the dictionary key, as in

```
 SortDict = {'Jan-':1,'Feb-':2,'Mar-':3,'Q1':4 ... 'Sum':n}
```

Then sort each year's list according to the dictionary.  You may want to reference, this other [question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35789546/python-sorting-list-based-on-the-values-of-dictionary).

Comment: Welcome to [so]! Good first post! However, questions with downvotes are often the hardest to answer well. It's best to avoid them.

Comment: The format I want is Janx, Febx, Marchx, Q1x,Win x-1, Aprx, Mayx, Junx, Q2x, Julx, Augx, Sepx, Q3, Sumx Octx, Novx, Decx, Q4x, x, Jan x+1, Febx+1, ....